# How to import angular 6 library into other library angular 6 library?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-library

I have created a shared library and created new application feature library and I want to import shared library in the app feature library.

How can I import or include one library into another library?

Comment: One of the method is to pack this library by using https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr and then include it in your projects in the package.json

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use your shared library as a node dependency in your application library.

Example: If you have created your shared library via npm command as follows:

```
ng generate library sharedlib
```

Then build your shared library and publish in any public (npmjs) or private (your organization specific like JFrog) artifactory with following command

```
npm publish sharedlib
```

And use it as dependency (add in package.json) in your application library as

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.0",
    "sharedlib": "1.0.0"
}
```

I believe importing shared library module (from public-api.ts file) in application library (if both in same repository) can also work, but that is not a best way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

You should add any library you use as peerDependencies in your library's package.json. Something like this:

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.7"
}
```

Assuming you've created the library using the cli with `ng generate library my-library`, the **peerDependencies** node is already there.

This will avoid any conflict if the user of your library also uses the other ones too.

Comment: Your welcome! Please accept the answer if it was helpful.